# How high is GeoPositionAccuracy.High?

Tags: geolocation, windows-phone, windows-phone-8

When working with the Windows Phone Location API, I am trying to gauge distance between two points that are only say inches or feet away. That said, accuracy is very important.

What is the difference between *GeoPositionAccuracy.Default* and *GeoPositionAccuracy.High*? Is the difference related to the number of decimal values? If that is the case, how many decimal values are assigned for *GeoPositionAccuracy.Default* and *GeoPositionAccuracy.High*?

Comment: [Maximum GPS accuracy is about three meters](http://www.gps.gov/systems/gps/performance/accuracy/). There are various augmentation systems like WAAS available to increase the accuracy, but AFAIK most of these are too expensive or big to fit inside a phone. Measuring distances below a meter means you're going to have a very big margin of error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GeoPositionAccuracy` is just used to tell Windows Phone whether you need an accurate position or not. You get to make that choice because a higher accuracy uses more battery, so it's better not using it if you're just trying to figure out in which town the user is currently located. `GeoPositionAccuracy.Default` probably doesn't even use the GPS, but [alternative localization methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_phone_tracking#Handset-based)

For the actual accuracy of the position you get, you can check the [`HorizontalAccuracy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.device.location.geocoordinate.horizontalaccuracy%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) property of the [`GeoCoordinate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.device.location.geocoordinate%28v=vs.92%29.aspx). It gives you the error margin in meters.

Comment: @GrahamSmith For those questions, it's faster to directly ask MSDN ;) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.device.location.geocoordinatewatcher.movementthreshold(v=vs.92).aspx  "The distance, **in meters**, that must be travelled between successive PositionChanged events."

Answer (score 2):

GeoPositionAccuracy.Default uses a combination of the following:

- Assisted GPS (aka cell tower triangulation)
- Wi-Fi Triangulation (aka IP lookup)

GeoPositionAccuracy.High uses the methods above, in addition to:

- GPS

Assisted GPS is battery friendly & locks on the location fast since it uses the cell radio which is already on. I can be accurate to the city block or building level in urban areas, but accuracy degrades in rural areas where the density of cell towers decreases. It also works well inside buildings.

GPS is slower to acquire a satellite lock and consumes more battery power since the GPS radio must be turned on as needed. Once locked in, it's the most accurate positioning method within just a few feet. It's virtually useless inside buildings since you need line of sight with the sky. Dense urban areas like Manhattan can also cause GPS inaccuracies.

Wi-Fi / IP Lookup is the least accurate since the IP address of an Wi-Fi hotspot can sometimes be registered at a different address.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe it makes any guarantees on the accuracy, it just allocates more resources towards acquiring a more accurate position (by providing more power to GPS module for instance).